# how to check condition of input based on data type

Tags: python

How to condition users input of num1 & num2, if it's in string with `if`/`else` or `try`/`except`? If someone enters a non-numeric string instead of number in `num1`/`num2`, it should throw an error. I don't know how to check that. This is what I have so far:

```
print("\n Select A Number \n")
print("Press 1 for Addition")
print("Press 2 for Subtraction")
print("Press 3 for multiplication")
print("Press 4 for Division \n")

while True:
    user = input("Enter A Choice(1/2/3/4): ")
    if user in ('1','2','3','4'):
        num1 = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))

        if user == '1':
            print(f"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}")
            print("Thanks For Usnig This Calculator")
        elif user == '2':
            print(f"{num1} - {num2} = {num1 - num2}")
            print("Thanks For Usnig This Calculator")
        elif user == '3':
            print(f"{num1} * {num2} = {num1 * num2}")
            print("Thanks For Usnig This Calculator")
        elif user == '4':
            print(f"{num1} / {num2} = {num1 / num2}")
            print("Thanks For Usnig This Calculator")
        else:
            print("Please Enter Correct Choice")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("\n Select A Number \n")
print("Press 1 for Addition")
print("Press 2 for Subtraction")
print("Press 3 for multiplication")
print("Press 4 for Division \n")

while True:
    user = input("Enter A Choice(1/2/3/4): ")
    if user in ('1','2','3','4'):
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
       
            if user == '1':
                print(f"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}")
                print("Thanks For Using This Calculator")
            elif user == '2':
                print(f"{num1} - {num2} = {num1 - num2}")
                print("Thanks For Using This Calculator")
            elif user == '3':
                print(f"{num1} * {num2} = {num1 * num2}")
                print("Thanks For Using This Calculator")
            elif user == '4':
                print(f"{num1} / {num2} = {num1 / num2}")
                print("Thanks For Using This Calculator")
            else:
                print("Please Enter Correct Choice")
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a number sucka, type again properly")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

This is the basic try catch block.
Go here if you want to learn more
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_exceptions.htm#:~:text=except%20ExceptionType%20as%20Argument%3A%20You,the%20tuple%20of%20the%20exception](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_exceptions.htm#:%7E:text=except%20ExceptionType%20as%20Argument%3A%20You,the%20tuple%20of%20the%20exception).